# Как изменить отображение inlines в django?

Tags: django

Всем привет, как можно изменить отображение Inlines. Сейчас они стоят в строку, как можно сделать в столбец? Стоит админка jazzmin. Возможно нужно как-то переписать стили, подскажите куда и как их переподключить, спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае вместо TabularInline нужно было использовать StackedInline